# ubuntu + nginx + laravel vue-material-dashboard

Tags: laravel, vue.js, ubuntu, nginx, vue-material

I tried a lot to get the "Vue-material-dashboard Laravel" working. Here is the [url](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/vue-material-dashboard-laravel) to the project.
I manage to serve the thing, but when I try to login and it says: "Invalid credentials".
Looks like this:
[image: notification here]

As you can see below I also send them a ticket ;) But have not gotten help from them yet, so I decided to see if someone can help me here

#### Version of Vue-material-dashboard Laravel

latest

#### Reproduction link

Nginx file:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com;
    
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name example.com;
    root /data/vue-material-dashboard-laravel/laravel-json-api/public;
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key.pem;    
    
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

   # location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
   #     deny all;
   # }
}
```

#### Operating System

Ubuntu

#### Device

server

#### Browser & Version

firefox, latest

#### Steps to reproduce

1. I set all up according to documentation and run npm run build.
2. I let nginx server the laravel/public folder. I use a rather minimal nginx configration in sites-enabled folder (see nginx code above)

#### What is expected?

I use the npm command, output tells me to look at http://example.com:8081
Everything looks fine and login should be working with default given login

#### What is actually happening?

### I get some sort of backend, but cannot login.
It says: "Invalid credentials"

#### Solution

Do you maybe have a nice example of how nginx should server the app?
I could not find anything online. I tried running vue-material-dashboard over https by adding "vue.config.js":

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    open: process.platform === 'darwin',
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 8081, // CHANGE YOUR PORT HERE!
    https: true,
    hotOnly: false,
  },
}
```

Then indeed everything goes through https but login does still not work. Any ideas why? Seems api does not communicatie well with vue

#### Additional comments

If we can let it all work on a linux server we woudl want to go and buy the PRO version eventually (after we tested it and so on)